# Empty properties? when I call $web.GetFile() method from Powershell

Tags: powershell, error, url, spweb, sitepages

I wonder why when I execute this two lines

```
$wpDestinationPageFullUrl = "http://root/sites/SitioModelo/TestLoadWebPart/SitePages/HomeTest.aspx"
$siteUrl = "http://root/sites/SitioModelo/TestLoadWebPart/"
$Web = Get-SPWeb -identity $siteUrl
$spFile = $Web.GetFile($wpDestinationPageFullUrl)
```

in the console when I type $spFile show me this output

```
EffectiveRawPermissions : 
EffectiveAuditMask      : 
Exists                  : False
Properties              : 
ForwardLinks            : 
BackwardLinks           : 
Title                   : 
Length                  : 
TotalLength             : 
LengthByUser            : 
Author                  : 
ModifiedBy              : 
TimeCreated             : 
TimeLastModified        : 
CustomizedPageStatus    : 
ETag                    : 
LockType                : 
LockId                  : 
LockedDate              : 
LockExpires             : 
LockedByUser            : 
CheckOutStatus          : 
CheckOutType            : 
CheckedOutDate          : 
CheckOutExpires         : 
CheckedOutBy            : 
CheckedOutByUser        : 
CheckInComment          : 
Generator               : 
CharSetName             : 
ProgID                  : 
UIVersion               : 
MajorVersion            : 
MinorVersion            : 
UIVersionLabel          : 
ParentFolder            : SitePages
Url                     : SitePages/Home.aspx
UniqueId                : 44cdd661-401d-4aa7-8b0b-149067408996
ServerRelativeUrl       : /sites/testsite/childtest/SitePages/Home.aspx
IconUrl                 : ichtm.gif
Name                    : Home.aspx
RequiresCheckout        : 
DocumentLibrary         : 
Versions                : 
Item                    : 
ListItemAllFields       : 
InDocumentLibrary       : 
Level                   : 
IsConvertedFile         : 
SourceLeafName          : 
SourceUIVersion         : 
GeneratingConverterId   : 
SourceFile              : 
Web                     : 
ServerRedirected        : 
IsIRMed                 : False
IsSharedAccessRequested : False
EventReceivers          :
```

Why many properties are empty? There is an error en my page? Maybe I have to configure this site?

Thanks!

Comment: from your output, it appears that the file you are trying to query does not exist!

Comment: That is the problem.. that file exist!! because i can insert this url "http://root/sites/SitioModelo/TestLoadWebPart/SitePages/HomeTest.aspx" in the browser and access to see. But al properties are empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think your file does not exist, or you are not setting the url parameter correctly.

Double check `$wpDestinationPageFullUrl`.

```
$web.GetFile

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile GetFile(string strUrl)
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile GetFile(guid uniqueId)
```

Comment: The value of the variable should be the full url? I mean I have this  "http://root/sites/SitioModelo/TestLoadWebPart/SitePages/HomeTest.aspx" is a page that I create to test and the url is exaclty like that.

Comment: because you don't show us your actual urls, it's hard to see what you are doing. I suggest that you instantiate SPWeb object based on the same website url as the one the file is located in.

Comment: Ok sorry.. I updated the snipped.

Comment: try $wpDestinationPageFullUrl = "/sites/SitioModelo/TestLoadWebPart/SitePages/HomeTest.aspx"